# Jasmine karma not working with simple unit test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm new with angular, karma and jasmine, I want to begin unit testing the project I work on, but I'm struggling making this whole lot of things working.

My specific problem is when I try to run a simple test. This piece of code gives the following error:

```
Error: Provider capitalizeFilter must define $get factory method.
at Error (native)
at provider (C:/projects/gsmobile/src/js/vendor/libraries.min.js:11:24305)
at factory (C:/projects/gsmobile/src/js/vendor/libraries.min.js:11:24435)
at Object.factory (C:/projects/gsmobile/src/js/vendor/libraries.min.js:11:24106)
at $FilterProvider.register (C:/projects/gsmobile/src/js/vendor/libraries.min.js:13:30582)
at C:/projects/gsmobile/src/js/vendor/libraries.min.js:11:25568
at Array.forEach (native)
at forEach (C:/projects/gsmobile/src/js/vendor/libraries.min.js:11:5733)
at loadModules (C:/projects/gsmobile/src/js/vendor/libraries.min.js:11:25102)
at Object.createInjector [as injector] (C:/projects/gsmobile/src/js/vendor/libraries.min.js:11:28387)
```

Now, the error stops if I remove the line that is indicate belowd. But My guess is that I'm not configuring well the karma config file or something.

```
describe('Initial test', function(){

  var _testService, _scope;

  beforeEach(module('GS'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(testService, $rootScope){

    _testService = testService;

    _scope = $rootScope;

  }));

  it("If I delete this line everything works", function(){ });

});
```

I have no clue of what is: "capitalizeFilter" maybe there is some file that I'm not getting well in the files configuration of karma.

I hope that somebody have some clues of what is happening that could shed some lights on this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: can you share your karma.config and testService.js?

Comment: Seeing testService would help. Also, make sure you're using the correct module. I would try scoping that down to only what testService needs. Typically you'll see the error you are getting if you inject a provider that doesn't have a this.$get method defined. Providers will get newed up when they are injected in. It seems like capitalizeFilter is missing this. Example: .provider('someProvider', function (){this.$get = [function (){return {something: orOther}}];};

Comment: Here they are: testService.js https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4f7d63d61380fb598cb0
and karma.config.js
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0d2202cbac89dde075af